# Execute a command stored in a variable

Tags: bash, cpu, shell

I want to write script that will show cpu utilization for one service. below is script and output for the same. Kindly assist.

Script :

```
yourpid=$(service tomcat_SP status | cut -d':' -f2) #this will store PID

newpid="${yourpid// /}" # this will remove extra space from PID

final=$(ps -p $newpid -o %cpu=) # this is final command to get cpu utilization

$final # calling command to give output
```

Script Output :

```
[root@PHYAPP01 tmp]# sh -x temp.sh

++ service tomcat_SP status

++ cut -d: -f2

+ yourpid=' 1823'

+ newpid='1823'

+ ps -p 1823 -o %cpu=

ERROR: Process ID list syntax error.

********* simple selection *********  ********* selection by list *********

-A all processes                      -C by command name

-N negate selection                   -G by real group ID (supports names)

-a all w/ tty except session leaders  -U by real user ID (supports names)

-d all except session leaders         -g by session OR by effective group 
name

-e all processes                      -p by process ID
```

Comment: Please use code tags to properly format the code in your post.

Comment: Try running `ps -p 1823 -o %cpu=` on command prompt and let us know whether it works..

Answer (score 0):

The last two commands of your script:

```
final=$(ps -p $newpid -o %cpu=)
$final
```

The first will run the `ps` command and store its output in the `final` variable.  The second command will prompt the shell to use the output of `ps` as a command, which will fail.

These two lines should be replaced with the single line

```
ps -p $newpid -o %cpu=
```

However, the script errors out *before* getting to the last line. The error indicates that you're calling `ps` in the wrong way. Maybe this particular `ps` implementation doesn't understand `-o`, or the format (`%cpu=`) is incorrect.

Try using `-o pcpu=` or `-o pcpu` instead.